# Access violation error at (while (info[x] != ' '))

Tags: c++, loops, cstring

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char info[81];
    string names[5];
    double sales[5][5];
    int count = 0;
    int x = 0;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("sales.txt");

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        x = 0;
        file.getline(info, 80);
        while(info[x] != (char)39)
        {
            while(info[x] != ' ')
            {
                names[count] += info[x];
                x++;
            }
            x++;
            for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                sales[count][atoi(&info[x])] = (atoi(&info[x + 1]) * 10) + atoi(&info[x+2]) + (.01 *((atoi(&info[x+4])*10) + atoi(&info[x+5])));
                x += 7;
            }
            x++;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

I get a runtime error when i run this but i cant figure out exactly why. im not very familiar with my compilers debugger so i am having trouble debugging.

Comment: What horrors of code. Do you have a really, really good reason why you can't use `std::string` and `std::getline`? Nobody can seriously want to debug *that* mess.

Comment: If you say `(char)39`, then you should also say `x = (int)0`, non?

Answer (score 4):

I would think 'x' is exceeding the array (info) bounds. You should check that x is less than 81 before entering the loop again.

Ex:

```
while(x < 81 && info[x] != (char)39)
    {
        while(info[x] != ' ')
        {
            names[count] += info[x];
            x++;
        }
        x++;
        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
        {
            sales[count][atoi(&info[x])] = (atoi(&info[x + 1]) * 10) + atoi(&info[x+2]) + (.01 *((atoi(&info[x+4])*10) + atoi(&info[x+5])));
            x += 7;
        }
        x++;
    }
```

Anyway, the same could happen in the lines that are inside the loop. You are supposing that your input will have strings with certain length, and if it doesn't happen, you'll get that error again.

---

If you are trying to divide each line in spaces, you could consider using formatted input instead (for each line):

```
        stringStream >> names[count];
        string theNextString;
        stringStream >> theNextString;
        // Process the theNextString, which is the string after the last space (and until the next one)
```

Also, this line is very error-prone. I suggest you to divide it in smaller parts easier to understand (and less dependent on the exact length of the line). You could even use formatted input to get the numbers.

```
sales[count][atoi(&info[x])] = (atoi(&info[x + 1]) * 10) + atoi(&info[x+2]) + (.01 *((atoi(&info[x+4])*10) + atoi(&info[x+5])));
```

Using formatted input, it would look like

```
int firstNumber;
stringStream >> firstNumber;
```

Please note that the above will only work if your numbers are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

After checking again, I surmise that it's probably this line of your code:

```
sales[count][atoi(&info[x])] = (atoi(&info[x + 1]) * 10) + atoi(&info[x + 2]) + (.01 *((atoi(&info[x + 4]) * 10) + atoi(&info[x + 5])));
```

You're definitely going outside the bounds of `info`and stepping into some other memory location. This is mostly likely what's causing the memory-access violation.